How to disable application/json in Swagger UI autodocs of a FastAPI application?
My API can return only a file:
    @router.get(
        "/partners/{partner_id}/rsr-requests/{rsr_request_id}/{document_path}",
        responses={200: {"content": {"application/octet-stream": {}}, "description": "Файл"}}
    )
    async def download_rsr_document(...):
        pass

But in Swagger UI, I can see that application/json still remains. How to disable it?


From the docs you use the response_class parameter with the type of Response you want.
    from fastapi import FastAPI
    from fastapi.responses import FileResponse
    
    some_file_path = "large-video-file.mp4"
    app = FastAPI()
    
    
    @app.get("/", response_class=FileResponse)
    async def main():
        return some_file_path


Since your API can only return a file, you could then change the default  repsonse class (i.e., application/json) in FastAPI, as described in this answer (see the relevant documentation as well), using the default_response_class parameter.
Example
from fastapi import FastAPI
from fastapi.responses import FileResponse

some_file_path = "some-file.txt"
app = FastAPI(default_response_class=FileResponse)


@app.get("/")
async def main():
    return some_file_path
    #return FileResponse(some_file_path)  # should work as well

If you needed that change to take effect only on specific endpoint(s) in your API, you could then use the response_class parameter in your endpoint's decorator, as follows:
@app.get("/", response_class=FileResponse)
async def main():
    return some_file_path
    #return FileResponse(some_file_path)  # should work as well

